# SQL - How to use the output from an insert to update a table

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-update, sql-insert

### QUESTION INFO

**Detailed Question**

The best way I can explain my question is to explain my desired outcome. I'm trying to take a certain set of offices, insert its data into the dbo.DeliveryLocation table, then take the output *inserted.DeliveryLocationId* and update the corresponding office's *DeliveryLocationId* field with that id.

**Desired Outcome Example**

*Office Data Before*

```
OfficeId | DeliveryLocationId
-----------------------------
1        | null

2        | null

3        | null
```

> Run the SQL statement

*Office Data After*

```
OfficeId | DeliveryLocationId
-----------------------------
1        | 5

2        | 6

3        | 7
```

- Delivery Location with the DeliveryLocationId of 5 was created with
  the data of the Office with OfficeId of 1
- Delivery Location with the DeliveryLocationId of 6 was created with
  the data of the Office with OfficeId of 2
- Delivery Location with the DeliveryLocationId of 7 was created with
  the data of the Office with OfficeId of 3

**The problem**

Per my current SQL script below, you can see that I have the first part (inserting the Office data into the Delivery Location table) complete. The second part (updating the Office with the corresponding DeliveryLocationId of the created Delivery Location) is not complete, and I am unsure how to go about doing that.

**My initial thoughts/ solutions**

If there would be a way to store the correlated OfficeId and DeliveryLocationId, perhaps we could loop through them and update the offices in a second SQL statement rather than try to create one SQL statement that does everything.

### REFERENCES

**dbo.DeliveryLocation**

```
    [DeliveryLocationId] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [LocationName] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
    [ShortName] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
    [ValidatedAddressId] [int] NOT NULL,
    [DropoffInstruction] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
    [PickupInstruction] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
    [TaxRate] [decimal](18, 2) NOT NULL,
    [Active] [bit] NOT NULL,
    [DisableOffices] [bit] NOT NULL
```

**dbo.Office**

```
    [OfficeId] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [OfficeName] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
    [ValidatedAddressId] [int] NOT NULL,
    [ReferralSource] [nvarchar](max) NOT NULL,
    [NumberOfEmployees] [int] NOT NULL,
    [DeliveryLocationId] [int] NULL
```

**Current SQL**

```
insert into
    dbo.DeliveryLocation
(LocationName, ShortName, ValidatedAddressId, Active, DisableOffices)
output
    inserted.DeliveryLocationId
select 
    OfficeName, OfficeName, ValidatedAddressId, 0, 0 
from
    dbo.Office as o
where
    OfficeId in
    (
    select distinct 
        OfficeId 
    from 
        dbo.[User] as u
    where
        u.DeliveryLocationId is null
    and
        u.OfficeId is not null
    )
```

Comment: This is a one and done process. From a high level perspective, it's the beginning of a data migration plan.

Comment: Are you able to modify the table structure as part of this?  A solution would be to temporarily add a new column to the `DeliveryLocation` table that allows you to insert the `OfficeId` into it.  Then use this to update the `Office.DeliveryLocationId` column.  Once completed, remove the new column from `DeliveryLocation`.

Comment: @MartinParkin I have full permissions and abilities to do the above solution. My hesitation comes from the fact that the database is being generated from Entity Framework (CodeFirst). Long story short for those that aren't familiar with the former, the structure of the database is managed externally, and I'm not sure what the implications would be with manually modifying the structure, even temporarily.

Comment: You could use a CURSOR. It's a one time affair anyway, no performance issues are relevant, and it will be easy to do...

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure about doing this in an `INSERT` statement, but if you use a `MERGE` statement using Office (or a query based on Office) as the source, you'll be able to refer to source.OfficeId as well as inserted.DeliveryLocationId in the `OUTPUT` clause. You can simply skip the update and delete usage of the `MERGE`, and only use the `ON NOT MATCHED` clause.

When I'm doing things like this I put the output into a temp table, then carry out any further updates or inserts I need to do from there.

In case you've not used the `MERGE` statement before (or even for anyone who just hasn't used all of their capabilities), this is a really fantastic resource on how to use them, and how to use them well: http://www.made2mentor.com/2012/07/got-the-urge-to-merge/

Answer (score 0):

You could do an update join after you insert into delivery location

```
update dbo.Office
set o.DeliveryLocationID = dl.DeliveryocationID
from Office o
JOIN DeliveryLocation dl on dl.LocationName = o.OfficeName
```

Assuming that the Office Names are unique.  If they are not you may want to add OfficeID to the DeliveryLocations table, at least temporarily, and join on that.